# WineHD crashes when using Nvidia-340.107 drivers

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, wine, opengl

I am facing troubles with executing Age of Empires II - The Conquerors, not the HD version on WineHD.

I am currently on Ubuntu 18.04.02, with nvidia-driver 340.107 (my GPU is a Geforce GT 230M).

The strange thing is that if I am setting the nouveau drivers, everything works ""fine"" except that: 
- the GPU temperature goes up to 100°C, whereas with nvidia drivers attest on the more ""normal"" 75°C
- no matter which configuration of Wine I set, the game always starts in a small window and not fullscreen.

I would like to use the more efficient nvidia drivers, but when I run the same .exe I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x7c002fd4 in 32-bit code (0x7caab2ea).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7caab2ea ESP:0033b300 EBP:00000014 EFLAGS:00210202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:7d84ad20 EBX:7c002fd4 ECX:7d84ad20 EDX:00000000
 ESI:7cb24ad0 EDI:7c0005f9
Stack dump:
0x0033b300:  f7f17940 7c0008b4 00000149 0008c408
0x0033b310:  7c202490 00000000 f7f17940 00000012
0x0033b320:  00000016 7c1bd230 7c00082c 7caac52c
0x0033b330:  7c0008b4 00000014 7cb249c0 7c1bd230
0x0033b340:  00000000 f7f17040 f7f17940 00000285
0x0033b350:  f7f17504 f7c4bb96 7cea93d8 0000000a
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7caab2ea glGetTexGenivOES+0xffffffff() in libgl.so.1 (0x00000014)
  1 0x7caac52c glGetTexGenivOES+0xffffffff() in libgl.so.1 (0x7c00082c)
  2 0x7cab4e95 glGetTexGenivOES+0xffffffff() in libgl.so.1 (0x7cab1610)
  3 0x7ca8cb25 glGetTexGenivOES+0xffffffff() in libgl.so.1 (0x7c1ba020)
  4 0xf7eff79d _dl_find_dso_for_object+0xffffffff() in ld-linux.so.2 (0x7c1ba020)
  5 0xf7eff8de _dl_find_dso_for_object+0xffffffff() in ld-linux.so.2 (0xff94bcf0)
  6 0xf7f03855 _dl_find_dso_for_object+0x9e4() in ld-linux.so.2 (0x0033b668)
  7 0xf7c4bc20 getfsent+0x42d0f() in libc.so.6 (0xf7f17504)
  8 0xf7f02fe6 _dl_find_dso_for_object+0x175() in ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f17504)
  9 0xf7b12c65 GLIBC_2+0xc64() in libdl.so.2 (0xff94bcf0)
  10 0xf7c4bc20 getfsent+0x42d0f() in libc.so.6 (0x0033b9d8)
  11 0xf7c4bcd0 getfsent+0x42dbf() in libc.so.6 (0x0033b9d8)
  12 0xf7b133c1 GLIBC_2+0x13c0() in libdl.so.2 (0x0033b9d8)
  13 0xf7b12d28 GLIBC_2+0xd27() in libdl.so.2 (0x0033b9d8)
  14 0xf7d3d65f wine_dll_load+0xffffffff() in libwine.so.1 (0x0033b9d8)
  15 0x7dd3c838 X11DRV_ClipCursor+0x5537() in winex11 (0x0033bbe8)
  16 0x7bc8af6e RtlRunOnceExecuteOnce+0x4d() in ntdll (0x0033bc38)
  17 0x7b47bf61 InitOnceExecuteOnce+0x20() in kernel32 (0x0033bc68)
  18 0x7dd400f7 X11DRV_ClipCursor+0x8df6() in winex11 (0x0033bc98)
  19 0x7dd2f424 ImeGetImeMenuItems+0x903() in winex11 (0x0033bcb8)
  20 0x7e7e6f7e __wine_get_wgl_driver+0x4d() in gdi32 (0x0033bce8)
  21 0x7e138337 wined3d_buffer_incref+0xffffffff() in wined3d (0x0033be38)
  22 0x7e178777 wined3d_decref+0x796() in wined3d (0x0033c1c8)
  23 0x7e17c073 wined3d_device_create+0x222() in wined3d (0x0033c1e8)
  24 0x7e1f42f1 wined3d_create+0x50() in wined3d (0x0033c218)
  25 0x7e280cd4 DirectDrawCreateClipper+0x7a3() in ddraw (0x0033c3d8)
  26 0x7e2919e1 DirectDrawCreateClipper+0x114b0() in ddraw (0x0033c418)
  27 0x7e292354 DirectDrawCreate+0x53() in ddraw (0x0033c458)
0x7caab2ea glGetTexGenivOES+0xffffffff in libgl.so.1: movl  %eax,0x0(%ebx)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (126 modules)
PE    400000-  7e6000   Export          age2_x2
PE   1050000- 110a000   Deferred        language_x1_p1
PE   9dc0000- 9e52000   Deferred        language
PE  10000000-1005e000   Deferred        language_x1
PE  5e080000-5e0bb000   Deferred        dplayx
PE  6ad80000-6ad95000   Deferred        miniupnpc
ELF 7826c000-7a800000   Deferred        libnvidia-glcore.so.340.107
ELF 7a800000-7a93e000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a93e000   \               opengl32
ELF 7ac00000-7ac86000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac86000   \               riched20
ELF 7b400000-7b7f8000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7f8000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd00000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bd00000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c066000-7c18f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7c080000-7c18f000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7c28f000-7c370000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7c370000-7c400000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7c45e000-7c476000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c476000-7c48c000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF 7c48c000-7c4e7000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7ca0e000-7cb25000   Dwarf           libgl.so.1
ELF 7cf3a000-7cf66000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7cf66000-7cf7e000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cf7e000-7d009000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d009000-7d03f000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d03f000-7d063000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  7d050000-7d063000   \               shcore
ELF 7d06f000-7d078000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d078000-7d07d000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d07d000-7d0b9000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d0b9000-7d0ce000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d0ce000-7d24f000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF 7d24f000-7d26d000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF 7d26d000-7d3bb000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d3bb000-7d3c8000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d3c8000-7d3cd000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d3cd000-7d402000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d402000-7d4de000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d4de000-7d4f2000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d4f2000-7d500000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d500000-7d696000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d696000-7d6ea000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d6ea000-7d77d000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d78e000-7d7a2000   Deferred        riched32<elf>
  \-PE  7d790000-7d7a2000   \               riched32
ELF 7d849000-7d84e000   Deferred        libnvidia-tls.so.340.107
ELF 7d895000-7d8b3000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d8d8000-7d990000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7d8f0000-7d990000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7d990000-7d9ff000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d9a0000-7d9ff000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7d9ff000-7da94000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7da10000-7da94000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7da9b000-7dad3000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7daa0000-7dad3000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dad3000-7dada000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dada000-7dae6000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7dae6000-7daf9000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7daf9000-7dafd000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dafd000-7db0a000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7db0a000-7db16000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7db16000-7db1d000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7db1d000-7db21000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7db21000-7db2b000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7db2b000-7db46000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7db46000-7db4d000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7db4d000-7db51000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7db51000-7db7d000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7db7d000-7dcc7000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dcc7000-7dcdc000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dd01000-7dd91000   Dwarf           winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dd10000-7dd91000   \               winex11
ELF 7dedb000-7df0d000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7df0d000-7df58000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7df58000-7df77000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7df77000-7dfb1000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7dfb1000-7e06e000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e093000-7e0be000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e0a0000-7e0be000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e0be000-7e0f5000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e0d0000-7e0f5000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e0f5000-7e10f000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7e100000-7e10f000   \               wsock32
ELF 7e10f000-7e260000   Dwarf           wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e120000-7e260000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e260000-7e2d7000   Dwarf           ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7e270000-7e2d7000   \               ddraw
ELF 7e2d7000-7e322000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e322000   \               dsound
ELF 7e322000-7e346000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e330000-7e346000   \               imm32
ELF 7e346000-7e38c000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7e350000-7e38c000   \               usp10
ELF 7e38c000-7e4c9000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e390000-7e4c9000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e4c9000-7e4f5000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4d0000-7e4f5000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e4f5000-7e57a000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e500000-7e57a000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e57a000-7e6d5000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e590000-7e6d5000   \               ole32
ELF 7e6d5000-7e74e000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6e0000-7e74e000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e74e000-7e87d000   Dwarf           gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e760000-7e87d000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e87d000-7ea86000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e890000-7ea86000   \               user32
ELF 7ea86000-7eb3f000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7ea90000-7eb3f000   \               winmm
ELF 7eb3f000-7eb6b000   Deferred        msvfw32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb40000-7eb6b000   \               msvfw32
ELF 7eb6b000-7eb7f000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eb7f000-7eb9a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7eb9a000-7eba8000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eed9000-7efdb000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7b12000-f7b17000   Dwarf           libdl.so.2
ELF f7b17000-f7cf3000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7cf3000-f7d12000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d16000-f7d20000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7d37000-f7eee000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7ef0000-f7f18000   Dwarf           ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000023    0
    00000020    0
    0000001b    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001a    0
0000001e winedevice.exe
    00000026    0
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001f    0
00000024 explorer.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000025    0
0000002b (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Age of Empires II\age2_x1\age2_x2.exe
    0000002c    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.0
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-45-generic
```

It seems that the page fault is cause by the libgl.so.1. The output of the `find /usr/ -iname "libgl.so.1" | xargs file` command is:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1: symbolic link to libGL.so.340.107
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1:   symbolic link to libGL.so.340.107
```

Comment: so what's your exact setup? are you playing age of empires 1? age of empires 2? age of empires 2 hd? the best way might vary according to which one and how you own it.

Comment: I am playing Age of Empires II - The Conquerors , not the HD version.

Comment: However I would rather focus on the strange thing that the game **starts** with the nouveau driver, whereas it doesn't with the nvidia ones. 

Do nouveau-drivers use the libGL.so library as well? If so, why does that library crashes only when nvidia drivers are in use?

Answer (score 0):

For Age of Empires II - The Conquerors , not the HD version, I would recommend you use lutris :

(in terminal) :

```
ver=$(lsb_release -sr); if [ $ver != "18.10" -a $ver != "18.04" -a $ver != "16.04" ]; then ver=18.04; fi
echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_$ver/ ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris.list
wget -q https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_$ver/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

you can close that terminal and  hit "Start" and search for "Lutris" and launch it.

then go here : https://lutris.net/games/age-of-empires-ii-the-conquerors/ (with either firefox or chrome, not chromium)

click the install button on the version you want. It will start the install process in lutris.

follow the install procedure.

test how it runs.

at the end you can fiddle arround with the wine settings of that perticular install to make it run even better. I've been getting incredibly good results by using wine version : proton 3.17-beta and emulated desktop (doesn't change anything visually)

Comment: I never explicitly installed the nvidia drivers, they updated when installing the 18.04

I quote the output of the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` which says:
**For G8x, G9x and GT2xx GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.107)**

Comment: Yes, I've updated it, sorry. 
After running that command, I still have the same drivers list in the software update center, which is basically:
- nvidia-340.107
- nvidia-304.137 
- nouveau

Comment: so why not try 304.137 ...and then try my method for installing and playing the game. I think your wine version might have also been at fault. (proton is much much better)

Comment: because with my GPU is reccomended the 340, and the 304 is old an at the end of life (as it says the output of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`: 

** For GF1xx GPUs use `nvidia-390` (390.87)
For G8x, G9x and GT2xx GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.107)
For NV4x and G7x GPUs use `nvidia-304` (304.137) End-Of-Life! **

Comment: my bad. i keep mixing those two numbers in my head. ok let's assume the graphics driver is correct. let's try lutris.

Comment: I am installing it. However, I again take the chance to ask why the libGL.so brings or not to a page fault, depending on the drivers used. In the end, the library is the same, right?

Comment: but the way it's accessed (or even not accessed) is very likely different. I don't code graphics drivers, or stuff resembling that, so I don't know exactly what or why but all I can tell you is that this discrepency between Nouveau and Nvidia doesn't suprise me and it is likely one of many rather than one of few. know that what pipeline wine tries to access, openGL or vulkan or other and how, will also depend on what wine version you are using.

Comment: Okay, I got stucked as the version I am currently in possess of AoE is the one that does not require the installation, but directly extracts and plays. Lutris seems to require the CD or the setup.exe file

Comment: maybe allow it to skip that step/close. (your lutris AoE entry should remain) and then manually drop your AoE folder in the `Program Files (x86)` of your newly created lutris wineprefix. (should be under `~/.local/share/lutris/runners/AoEprefixname/drive_c/`. you can also "browse files" from the lutris config of that launcher) then edit the lutris configuration to make sure it's pointing the the right .exe and try to run it.

Comment: just FYI, you shouldn't be asking for advice on pirated software on this site, but for this game in particular there's no real reason not to succumb to the temptation of a steam or humble bundle sale for the HD version. I got mine for 4 bucks. that's really dirt cheap. and with the steam native vay you get the added bonus of not having to fiddle with wine at all. it takes care of all that. and it runs better. for my lan parties, I only use HD. it's so much less of a hassle to set up. but this game does have horrendous netcode.

Comment: Even by installing the game through lutris, the error is always the same (of course, I would say, considering that in the end lutris itself just relies on Wine )

Comment: not necessarily. there's not just one flavour of wine. have you gone ahead and launched the game from lutris (using the instructions I gave just above for utilising the created lutris runnable) ? did you try changing the wine settings in the options of that lutris runnable? setting it to a proton version of wine is bound to have positive effects.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find the one you referred, so I am trying with wine 3.21 or 4.01, or others. I do not get the error anymore, as the program simply does not start.

Comment: If I run `winecfg` the result is: 

0024:err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
000d:err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
0009:err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.

Comment: well that's pretty verbose. either you use nouveau, or dual boot windows 98 on it or you get a newer laptop.